# Ubuntu 22.04 black screen after bootup following some package upgrades

Tags: 22.04, display-manager

I updated the following packages via the CLI (from another device) and now after Ubuntu has booted, I am just presented with a black screen...

```
apparmor/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1]
gnome-remote-desktop/jammy-updates 42.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 42.0-4ubuntu1]
grub-efi-amd64-bin/jammy-updates 2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 2.06-2ubuntu10]
grub-efi-amd64-signed/jammy-updates 1.187.3~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu14.1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.182~22.04.1+2.06-2ubuntu10]
libapparmor1/jammy-updates 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.0.4-2ubuntu2.1]
shim-signed/jammy-updates 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9]
```

The problem is, I'm not sure which of these caused the problem and I can't find anything that jumps out in any log files. Presumably it is something to do with the `gnome-remote-desktop` but I'm unsure for certain.

Does anyone know what I could do to figure out what has broken so that I can determine how to fix this please?

If it's of any relevance, my VNC connection has also stopped working and now just times out - which is of no surprise if the GUI isn't working I guess.

## Edit

I rolled back the `gnome-remote-desktop` package and rebooted but that made no difference. I am trying to do the same with each one but it won't let me roll back the grub packages due to dependency problems with `shim-signed` which also won't roll back (see below):

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading shim-signed from 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 to 1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9
(Reading database ... 231440 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../shim-signed_1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking shim-signed (1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9) over (1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up shim-signed (1.51+15.4-0ubuntu9) ...
Installing grub to /boot/efi.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

Comment: On boot up try an older kernel.

Comment: @David I don't have any other kernels available to select.